# Old Toshiba Laptop Windows 7 AMD Cpu Upgrade

Tags: windows-7, laptop, performance, cpu

I want to be able to upgrade my Toshiba laptop from a C-50 dual core CPU to something better around say 2.50Ghz or at least 2Ghz.

I don't know the exact socket of the CPU but I think that it is a 
FT1 BGA 413-Ball but I am not exactly sure. My laptop is a Toshiba Satellite Windows 7 AMD and if there is a better CPU I can buy please list them below. I don't want to pay for another PC since this is my old one and I want to use it to edit videos but the rendering is really slow.

If you guys need anymore info on my laptop then please just ask me and I will give you the exact specs since I can't really and don't have time right now. I can't list them all because they are too much but the CPU should be enough for you to know.

Comment: also my cpu speed curently is only 1ghz :C so thats why i want to buy a better one and don't worry if it will cause my computer to burn or anything like that because i have the answer for those over heating problems

Comment: http://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-C-50-Notebook-Processor.40960.0.html                  credits to this website for helping me try to figure out if it was the right socket i mentioned in my question

Comment: The type of CPU you have cannot be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Download AIDA64 Extreme and run. http://www.aida64.com/downloads

Goto motherboard then motherboard look down and read off CPU Socket / Slot.

If the information says TRAIL then close program reopen and go there again. It randomly covers the information TRAIL Version.

You now will have the information your chasing however this does not mean upgraded cpu will work on your motherboard they sometimes need code injection to be accepted.  I don't think this is an issue for Toshiba Boards but worth noting it might be.

Comment: The author has a BGA CPU they are not going to be able to remove and replace the CPU

Comment: You are correct that CPU is connected to the board and unable to be removed.